# How do I load session and cookies from requests library to Selenium browser in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

i have this code to save cookies from requests

```
pickle.dump(session.cookies.get_dict(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
```

i wanna to use it in selenium browser so i used this code but it doesn't work

```
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

i get this error message

```
driver.add_cookie(cookie)
  File "C:\Users\Allah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 894, in add_cookie
    self.execute(Command.ADD_COOKIE, {'cookie': cookie_dict})
  File "C:\Users\Allah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Allah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid type: string "wa-xd-sessionid", expected struct AddCookieParameters at line 1 column 28
```

Comment: read about cookies in Selenium - it may need something different then dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

cookie is dictionary but adding it to selenium is different way of save it in file from requests session.

bellow code is example how get cookie from requests session and add it to selenium

```
ses = requests.session()
ses.get('https://www.google.com/')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
for item in ses.cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(
        {'httpOnly': False, 'name': item.name, 'value': item.value, 'domain': item.domain, 'path': item.path,
         'secure': item.secure})
```

Comment: Code-only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does and link the reference docs. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)